# Getting find: bad option -o -name abc -o -name xyz when perform search for *.properties excluding set of directories from search

Tags: find, directory, solaris, ksh

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

# *****************************************************************************************
# copy_properties.sh
# This script copies *.properties files from all directory excluding the 
# ones provided as the args. to a folder location of our choice.
# 
# *****************************************************************************************

echo "Starting the find and replace process for :" "$1"
set -x
# **************** Change Variables Here ************

startdirectory=$2 #"/home/ardsingh/test_properties/properties_files"
destinationFolder=$3

if [ -n "$4" ]; then
listOfFolderTobeIgnored=$4
#@list = split(/ /, $listOfFolderTobeIgnored);
#mapfile -t list << ($listOfFolderTobeIgnored)
IFS=' '
set -A list $listOfFolderTobeIgnored
foldersToBeIgnored="-o -name "${list[0]}
unset 'list[0]'
for item in "${list[@]}"
do
foldersToBeIgnored="$foldersToBeIgnored -o -name "
foldersToBeIgnored="$foldersToBeIgnored$item"
done
else
  echo "No input provided for folders to be ignored."
fi

#echo $foldersToBeIgnored

find "$startdirectory" -type d \( -name properties_file_folder_02_25 -o -name brmsdeploy -o -name TempJobs -o -name tmp -o -name logs -o -name deploy "$foldersToBeIgnored" \) -prune -o -name "*.properties" -type f -print -exec cp {} "$destinationFolder" \;
```

Getting below error:

```
find: bad option -o -name abc -o -name xyz
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Comment: Are you sure that this part ` -prune -o -name`is correct? Maybe you can debug this `find` statement by starting with a smaller number of concatenated `-name` filters and expand the statement in small steps.

Comment: Found the solution to the problem. was struggling for more than 2-3 hours. It turned out to be the problem with space. between -o -name deploy "$foldersToBeIgnored".  To fix it i changed it to -o -name deploy"$foldersToBeIgnored"

Comment: @mnille Yes the line pointed out by you is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than building up a *string* with command line options for ignoring directories with certain names, use an array. This way, the options for `find` that you add dynamically from the command line would be properly delimited.

The following script is a very basic one that takes a single search path, a destination directory, followed by any number of directory names to ignore.  The code builds up a set of options for `find` in `$@`, the array of positional parameters.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

searchpath=$1
destdir=$2
shift 2

ignore=( brmsdeploy TempJobs tmp logs deploy )

if [ ! -d "$destdir" ]; then
    printf 'Destination directory "%s" does not exist\n' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Process the directories to ignore from the command line.
# This replaces the positional parameters.
for name do
    set -- "$@" -o -name "$name"
    shift
done

# Process the directories that we always ignore.
# This adds to the positional parameters.
for name in "${ignore[@]}"; do
    set -- "$@" -o -name "$name"
done

shift # shift off the first -o

find "$searchpath" \( -type d \( "$@" \) -prune \) -o \
    \( -type f -name '*.properties' -exec cp {} "$destdir" \; \)
```

To use:

```
./script.sh /path/to/topdir /path/to/destdir somename someothername fluff
```

This would execute `find`, ignoring directories with names `somename`, `someothername`, and  `fluff`.  Note that this also allows these names to contain spaces, tabs and newlines (if they are quoted on the command line).

The actual `find` command executed by this command would be

```
find /path/to/topdir '(' -type d '(' -name somename -o -name someothername -o -name fluff -o -name brmsdeploy -o -name TempJobs -o -name tmp -o -name logs -o -name deploy ')' -prune ')' -o '(' -type f -name '*.properties' -exec cp '{}' /path/to/destdir ';' ')'
```

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda for above snippet i will try it once. Will the above script work with Solaris as well as RHEL7. As my original script didn't worked well with Solaris, so i had to do some alteration to make it work on Solaris.

Comment: @ArdhenduShekharSingh I believe that the script would work with `ksh`/`ksh93` or `bash` regardless of the actual Unix being used.